# To send the details in multiple sheets in a single mail using a macro in Excel

Tags: vba, excel, email

Whenever I run a macro, I need to send certain Range of cells in different sheets to a Particular mail ID.

```
Sub Send_Range()

    Sheet1.Range("A2:V28").Select  

   ActiveWorkbook.EnvelopeVisible = True


   With ActiveSheet.MailEnvelope
     ' .Introduction = "This is a sample worksheet."
      .Item.To = "pkumar11@amgen.com"
      .Item.Subject = "My subject"
      .Item.Send
   End With
End Sub
```

Using this code I am able to send all Values of Range (A2:V28) from Sheet 1 in a mail. But I also want to send Values of Range (B3:F28) from Sheet 2 along with the values in sheet 1 in a single mail. Please help me.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a function written by Ron de Bruin that allows you to convert ranges into HTML:

```
Sub SendRange()
Dim mailApp As Object, mail As Object  
Dim rng As Range, rng1 As Range   

Set mailApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
Set mail = mailApp.createitem(0)

Set rng = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A2:V28").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
Set rng1 = Sheets("Sheet2").Range("B3:F23").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)

With mail
    .To = "pkumar11@amgen.com"
    .Subject = "My subject"
    .HTMLBody = RangetoHTML(rng) & "<br>" & RangetoHTML(rng1)
    .display
End With

End Sub

Function RangetoHTML(rng As Range)
' Changed by Ron de Bruin 28-Oct-2006
' Working in Office 2000-2016
    Dim fso As Object
    Dim ts As Object
    Dim TempFile As String
    Dim TempWB As Workbook

    TempFile = Environ$("temp") & "\" & Format(Now, "dd-mm-yy h-mm-ss") & ".htm"

    'Copy the range and create a new workbook to past the data in
    rng.Copy
    Set TempWB = Workbooks.Add(1)
    With TempWB.Sheets(1)
        .Cells(1).PasteSpecial Paste:=8
        .Cells(1).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues, , False, False
        .Cells(1).PasteSpecial xlPasteFormats, , False, False
        .Cells(1).Select
        Application.CutCopyMode = False
        On Error Resume Next
        .DrawingObjects.Visible = True
        .DrawingObjects.Delete
        On Error GoTo 0
    End With

    'Publish the sheet to a htm file
    With TempWB.PublishObjects.Add( _
         SourceType:=xlSourceRange, _
         Filename:=TempFile, _
         Sheet:=TempWB.Sheets(1).Name, _
         Source:=TempWB.Sheets(1).UsedRange.Address, _
         HtmlType:=xlHtmlStatic)
        .Publish (True)
    End With
```

Comment: You should use `Option Explicit` to be forced to declare all variables and avoid quite a lot of issue. Further more, here as `mailApp` and other Outlook related variables aren't declared, you may try to use Late Binding (`Dim ... As Object` and no reference to Outlook lib) and there `olMailItem` won't be recognized, so you could use `0` instead which is the value of that constant. ;)

Comment: @R3uK thanks for the feedback! I have updated my code accordingly.

Comment: You are welcome! ;) I'm becoming paranoid about it because I sudendly had a new error with declaration of my variable from a external reference in a quite long project! I would have lost hours without `Option Explicit` to change my code!^^

Comment: Yeah, I really got to start using `Option Explicit` to improve my coding. Bad habits die hard...

Comment: Just go into the tools/options of VBE and check the uncheck option (don't remember the name exactly) you'll have it in every new module! ;) (personally I also uncheck the auto check of syntax, it avoid message when you want to change line before finishing it, and still change the color of the line to red, it's less painful to work like this! ;)